# XAMPP relative URLs working on WordPress home but not pages

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a testing site at tektonpress.piconmedia.com that is working correctly.

I'm having some problems with relative URLs and images on a local version.

I installed XAMPP, restored a copy of the database to my local machine, and copied FTP files over. After updating wp-config.php, just about everything is working correctly. That includes images that use relative URLs in my stylesheets.

My problem is with some images that I try to load through HTML. They display correctly on the home page, but not from other pages.

For example, the following HTML works on localhost/tektonpress/ but not localhost/tektonpress/editing/:

```
<img src="resources/img/logo-white.png" alt="Tekton Press logo">
```

Here's an example when the image doesn't work:

[Example from page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj6Q8.jpg)

The image in question is located at C:\xampp\htdocs\tektonpress\resources\img\logo-white.png

When I hover over the URL while inspecting the element in Chrome, here's what I see:

[One layer too deep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7vOd.jpg)

I tried adding a slash to the front of the path, like so:

```
<img src="/resources/img/logo-white.png" alt="Tekton Press logo">
```

Unfortunately, the page ends up looking for the image at /localhost/resources/img/logo-white.png.

I've spent several hours on this with no luck. I thought I'd finally found a simple (but potentially maintenance-heavy) solution at stackoverflow.com/questions/7823260/xampp-relative-urls-not-working-correctly, but just ended up with a server error.

Here's the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /tektonpress/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /tektonpress/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `get_template_directory_uri().'/resources/img/logo-white.png'`

It should work. As I am assuming resources is in the base of your theme directory.

Comment: Tried `<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>resources/img/logo-white.png" alt="Tekton Press logo" />` but it looks like the theme provider (I'm using Thesis) prevents PHP code in text blocks. I'll investigate XAMPP issues with their support site and report back.

Comment: Saroj, that almost did it. Since I'm using Thesis, I installed [Tim Milligan's T2 PHP Box](https://github.com/voidzone/php-box). My images were actually above the theme directory, so here's what I used instead: `<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/resources/img/logo-white.png" alt="Tekton Press logo" />` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realize it is not much of a fix, but have you tried:

```
<img src="/tektonpress/resources/img/logo-white.png" alt="Tekton Press logo">
```

Should let you pull the image properly.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. No dice. Hovering over the element in Chrome Inspect returns "http://localhost/tektonpress/editing/tektonpress/resources/img/logo-white.png"

Comment: Change `RewriteRule . /tektonpress/index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`.

Comment: No luck there, either. localhost/tektonpress loads just fine, but attempting to navigate to pages like localhost/tektonpress/editing just sends me to localhost/dashboard.

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't be more help.